# Where Query Builder Method with Entity SQL parameters Error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to follow an example in Julia Lerman's book Programming Entity Framework 2nd edition and the following code wont work for me:

```
ObjectQuery<Contact> contacts = context.Contacts
                                .Where("it.FirstName = 'Robert'")
```

I get the following error:

> Argument2: can not convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expresions.Expression>'.

How can I access Where the Query Builder Method of ObjectQuery? I am using Entity Framework 6, the examples in the book are using Entity Framework 4. My context class inherits from `DbContext`, in the example in the book the context class inherits from `ObjectContext`.

Are query builder methods still used in Entity Framework 6?

Comment: `var contacts = context.Contacts.Where(it => it.FirstName == "Robert");` In this case its a lambda (linq expressions are also ok). You should read up on lambda syntax, here is a useful link: [Lambda Expressions - C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Ok but what is wrong with my code, is same as in the book, i don't want to use the IEnumerable.Where extension method. In my example Where is a Query Builder Method.

Comment: What is the type of `context` and also the type for the `Contacts` property? I had assumed `DbContext` and `DbSet<Contact>` respectively.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Im on Understanding Query Builder Methods, Julia Lerman's 2nd editon, page 235

Comment: It looks like the compiler is not using the correct Where method overload for some reason

Comment: See this link [ObjectQuery<T>.Where Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811(v=vs.100).aspx) for an example on how to use the query builder. The thing is this approach is dated compared to using an Expression which provides type safety. What is the publishing date?

Comment: As I said, the book is dated. No sense in struggling to get this to work, no new code uses it. If you really want to then get v4 of EF using NuGet but I recommend against it because why would you. EF 6 makes no use of the ObjectContext and no use of the Query Builder (*side note: yes, there is still a way to extract the ObjectContext from the internals of a DbContext but again, there is no good reason to do that in this case.*).

Comment: I would ignore the book and use more update to date references.  Your where clause is not [Type Safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).  Additionally, most programmers not familiar with [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) will not use parameters to create a safe query using your string.  Bottom line, just don't do that...ever.

Comment: It is published in 2010, and it is Entity Framework 4, i am using 6. In the book the context inherits from ObjectContext not DBContext, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @AlexeBarlescu - you hit the nail on the head, that is the exact reason why.

Comment: Also as you are new to learning EF there are many great online tutorials available including ones on the microsoft support site for EF. They are very easy to follow along with and will get you up and running faster than trying to follow Lerman's book only because that book is very dated.

Comment: So what book should i read on Entity framework? Would Julia Lerman's DBContext book whould be better? Im studiing for a Microsoft Ceritfication, and they still test Entity Sql, which yea is not type safe, and you have to pass this strings in the ObjectQuery objects.

Comment: 70-487 , actualy Entity Sql is not covered i exam , but quering with  Data Provider for Entity Framework is, and i think that might use Entity Sql.

Comment: It looks like this uses VS 2013 and EF5 so that does include the ObjectContext although they probably make use of Linq and Lambda expressions in the questions when using EF (and not straight ado.net) directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115562/discussion-between-igor-and-alexe-barlescu).

Answer (score 2):

> My context class inherits from DbContext, in the example in the book the context class inherits from ObjectContext.

First you have to change your context from DbContext into an ObjectContext like this:

```
var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

Now you can use use the Query Builder Method like this:

```
        var query = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>().Where("it.FirstName='Robert'").OrderBy("it.LastName");
```

Here is the whole example:

```
private static void OrderByAndWhereUsingEntitySQL_AndQueryBuilderMethods()
{
    using (var context = new AWEntities())
    {//using Entity SQL with helper Query Builder Methods
        //dbContext does not have a Where method that accepts esql string statements
        //get to the dbContext's ObjectContext class
        var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        //now we can use the Where method that understands esql string statements
        var query = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>().Where("it.FirstName='Robert'").OrderBy("it.LastName");
        //execute the query
        var customers = query.ToList();
        foreach (var cust in customers)
            Debug.WriteLine(cust.LastName.Trim() + ", " + cust.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a string, you need to use parameterization, and Where requires a second argument with the value.

I think just using straight LINQ with a lambda expression is cleaner.

Try:

```
ObjectQuery<Contact> contacts =
context.Contacts.Where("it.FirstName = @firstname",
new ObjectParameter("firstname", firstName));
```

Comment: Yes, but i'm trying to use 'Where' the Query Builder Method of ObjectQuery  class, to which you should be able to pass a string representing Entity Sql.

Comment: See updated query, I would use a lambda expression though.

Comment: I just want to just hard code the name like this "it.FirstName='Robert'". I get error.

Comment: If i run your example i get the error: No overload takes 2 arguments, because it is still refer to Where the linq extension method.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Linq queries do not provide an overload for `Where` with type `string`

Microsoft provides a NuGet library for parsing strings into Lambda expressions that can then be used in Linq queries called **System.Linq.Dynamic** which can be found here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/